# elasticsearch - search for numbers more than 2 decimal places

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I search for documents in elasticsearch that have numeric field with value having more than 2 decimal places?

My Mapping is as follows:

```
{
   "items": {
      "mappings": {
         "item": {
            "properties": {
               "id": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "item": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "price": {
                  "type": "double"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Sample document is as follows:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "item": "abc",
  "price": 1234.567
}
```

I get NumberFormatException when I try the following query:
GET items/_search

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "regexp": {"price": "[0-9]*\\.[0-9]{3,}"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get by doing this?

Comment: Please show your mapping and a query you're trying which doesn't yield what you expect.

Comment: @Val edited post with mapping and query

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use regular expression on number fields, unfortunately.

One possible way around this is to use a `script` query/filter like the one below. What it does is simply to check how many positions are available after the period and returns true if the number of positions is bigger or equals to 2.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "script": {
          "script": "def str = doc.price.value.toString(); def len = str.length(); def dot = str.indexOf('.'); return len - (dot+1) >= 2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did this help? Do you need more info?